# Java date pattern for deserializing date with variable number of fractional seconds?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, jackson, deserialization

I have a Java class being used in a Spring boot app to deserialize a json object coming from a request with a field like so:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]XXX", timezone = "UTC")
Instant timestamp;
```

It's using the Jackson V2.6.6 @JsonFormat annotation to deserialize the "timestamp" field in the JSON coming over the network.

What I'm seeing is that when the value is something like:

> "2017-01-09T21:49:26.70Z"

there are no issues.

However if the value has a single number of fractional second decimal places included, or more than three, like:

> "2017-01-09T21:49:26.7Z" or "2017-01-09T21:49:26.7000Z"

Then I'll get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-01-09T21:49:26.7Z' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:150) ~[jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:45) ~[jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserialize(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:156) ~[jackson-module-afterburner-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2764) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
```

What can I do to fix this pattern so that it can be flexible in terms of the number of fractional second decimal places it accepts? I understand there is a concept of lenient in Java date formatting: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

But I'm not sure how to set the object mapper to lenient mode.

Comment: If nothing works you can read it as `String` and parse it using a regular expression maybe

Answer (score 0):

## Update your Java implementation

Just a guess…

I suspect you may be hitting some java.time bugs in the earlier releases of Java 8. There were several parsing related bugs, some fixed in later updates of Java 8 and some fixed in Java 9.

I am guessing the `1.8.0_65` string in your error text refers to Java 8 Update 65. Currently the [Oracle implementation is at Update 121](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u-relnotes-2225394.html).

## What formatter?

I do not know [Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API)). I wonder what exact `DateTimeFormatter` they are invoking. I do not see that information in your error quote.

Can you omit defining the pattern and see what default behavior is for Jackson?

## No problem with `Instant.parse`

I see no such problem when parsing your strings by calling [`Instant.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) in Java 8 Update 121 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with 16 gigs of RAM running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with NetBeans 8.2.

```
System.out.println ( "Java vendor: " + System.getProperty ( "java.vendor" ) );
System.out.println ( "Java version: " + System.getProperty ( "java.version" ) );

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<> ();
strings.add ( "2017-01-09T21:49:26.7Z" );
strings.add ( "2017-01-09T21:49:26.70Z" );
strings.add ( "2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z" );
strings.add ( "2017-01-09T21:49:26.7000Z" );
strings.add ( "2017-01-09T21:49:26.70000Z" );

for ( String string : strings ) {
    try {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse ( string );
        System.out.println ( "GOOD - string: " + string + " parsed: " + instant );
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        System.out.println ( "ERROR - Failed to parse string: " + string );
    }
}
System.out.println ( "Done." );
```

When run.

```
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java version: 1.8.0_121
GOOD - string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.7Z parsed: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z
GOOD - string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.70Z parsed: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z
GOOD - string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z parsed: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z
GOOD - string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.7000Z parsed: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z
GOOD - string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.70000Z parsed: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z
```

You can also see this same [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/7YMn9w) without problem, running Java 8 Update 121 of the Oracle implementation.

## Problems with your `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`

I tried your formatting pattern as well. It works for `.70` and `.700` but not the others.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]XXX" , Locale.US );
for ( String string : strings ) {
    try {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( string , f );
        System.out.println ( "GOOD - string: " + string + " parsed: " + odt );
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        System.out.println ( "ERROR - Failed to parse string: " + string );
    }
}
System.out.println ( "Done with 'DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern'." );
```

```
ERROR - Failed to parse string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.7Z
GOOD - string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.70Z parsed: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z
GOOD - string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z parsed: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.700Z
ERROR - Failed to parse string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.7000Z
ERROR - Failed to parse string: 2017-01-09T21:49:26.70000Z
```

## ISO 8601

FYI, the format of strings such as `2017-01-09T21:49:26.70Z` is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use these standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing or generating strings representing date-time values.

That particular format uses a `T` to separate the year-month-date portion from the hour-minute-second portion. The `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

You can see much more info by [searching StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20parse%20iso%208601).

Comment: Just updated to 1.8.0.121 and it still fails on "2017-01-09T21:49:26.7Z" using the pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]XXX"

Comment: @AdamBronfin Get rid of the `@JsonFormat` altogether. If you do, Jackson will use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`, which is what `Instant#parse` uses which is what Basil suggests here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I agree with your suggestion as an experiment. But I added more code showing that his formatting pattern should be working just as well as `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`.

Comment: @AdamBronfin Have you tried copy-pasting code from my Answer or the working IdeOne.com code to see if they work on your setup?

Comment: You don't actually use the `DateTimeFormatter` you create.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis **Oops!** You are right, I failed to use the `DateTimeFormatter` object that I instantiated in my second example test. Now corrected, passing `f` in the `.parse` call. This gives me different results: That `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]XXX` pattern does *not* work with all the versions of data inputs. Thanks for catching my mistake. I updated [the code at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/7YMn9w).

Comment: The iso_instant formatter uses fractional digits which I don't think you can get with a string pattern.

Comment: Simply removing @JsonFormat seems to have done the trick. Thanks! Please submit this as an answer and I will accept.